# Beamer and Natbib

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, natbib

I'm making a beamer presentation and I'd like to use `natbib` because of its `\citet` and that it recognizes URLs. However, when I try to compile it, while doing the third PDFLaTeX pass, there appear this error (among others):

```
[28] (./presentacion.toc) [29] (./presentacion.bbl  

(./presentacion.toc  

! Missing } inserted.  

&lt;inserted text&gt;   

                }  

l.3 ...r@sectionintoc {1}{Introducci\'on}{4}{0}{1}
```

When I take out the `natbib` package, everything works well, including the `\bibliography`

Is there a way to solve this, or I shouldn't use `natbib` with `beamer`?

Comment: Minimal complete example? I have used beamer + natbib occasionally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `beamer` class is not working with `natbib`. The initial author of the class Till Tantau said:

> Currently, beamer does not work with
>   natbib since beamer meddles with the
>   same things as natbib and beamer's
>   meddling is not done in such a way
>   that natbib can tolerate this. Also,
>   it is not possible to "switch off
>   beamer's meddling"

However, you may use it in article mode.

You can read it [here](http://osdir.com/ml/tex.latex.beamer.general/2005-07/msg00005.html) in the tex.latex.beamer.general mailing list.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the things on the beamer 'to do' list. Not sure whether we'll tackle this any time soon.

Comment: It's really great that the development of beamer goes on.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a working example. I compiled this on MacTex-2009, using pdflatex. No errors, no warnings (except a message about pgfbaseimage.sty being obsolete, which is unrelated).

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\newblock}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    See \citet{foo}.

    \begin{thebibliography}{22}
        \bibitem[Foo(1988)]{foo} Foo (1998). Bar. \emph{CONF 1988}.
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is a PDF document that looks like this:

```
See Foo (1988).

Foo (1998). Bar. CONF 1988.
```

---

And another example using Bibtex; *test.tex*:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\newblock}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    See \citet{foo}.

    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and *test.bib*:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{foo,
    author={Bar Foo},
    year={1988},
    title={Foo},
    booktitle={CONF 1988}
}
```

Again, works fine.

Comment: Your post was very helpful for me. I want to say, though, that this second example is NOT straightforward at all. In particular `\newcommand{\newblock}{}` is a hack to get natbib and beamer working together. The beamer user guide suggests that only the manual bibliography entry approach is supported.

Comment: It worked for me with \renewcommand{\newblock}{}, great!

Comment: This second example does not work for me. Although I hoped it would!