# BibTeX and beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I'm working on a presentation that will be given to a very small group of people (3-5 people) that has a lot of citations (100-200), any one of which could be interesting to the audience at a given time. I was thinking that it would be nice to create a separate page (well, multiple pages) of references that the audience could refer to during my presentation. Can [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) do this? Can I use BibTeX at all with `beamer`?

The citations *must* be numbered in order that they are used, since sometimes I will reference 20 or 30 articles at once, and I need to be able to use the dash notation (i.e., `35-56` to cite all references from 35 to 56 at once).  Obviously, putting references on a slide at the end or at the bottom of the slides is not an option. I'd like to be able to apply a citation style file to the bibliography if possible. Also, numbering by hand isn't really an option, since I would have to renumber every time I added a citation.

Comment: Is the separate page to be a handout?

Comment: yes, that was my intention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you [can](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/beamer-and-natbib/1971#1971) use Bibtex with Beamer.

I guess something along these lines might work reasonably well:

- Prepare your Beamer slides as usual, using Bibtex. (You can hide the Bibtex-generated bibliography if you don't need it.)
- Prepare another Latex document (using e.g. the `article` class), in which you `\input` your Bibtex-generated *.bbl file.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid beamer of putting an icon at each reference on the references slides. But instead the usual numbers (citation with a number to a document that isn't shown in the references is strange).

Comment: I have exactly the same question as CommuSoft: I use bibtex with beamer, and the in-slide citations are numbered, but the entries in the bibliography are not, so there's no easy way to correlate citations with references.