# How to hide references from navigation bar in beamer class?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, formatting, navigation

I am doing a presentation using the `beamer` class with the `Warsaw` theme. Further, I have to disclose my bibliography at the end of the presentation. Unfortunately, as soon as I type in

```
\bibliography{}
```

it is automatically treated as another section and therefor displayed in the navigation bar. However, I would like to hide this from the navigation bar. If it was a "normal" section/subsection, I simply could rely on

```
\section[]{section1} or \subsection[]{1.1}
```

using empty square brackets. But obviously, as mentioned above, `beamer` treats the command for bibliography automatically as another section.

Hence, is there any simple code to hide exclusively the "reference section" from the navigation bar?

I am using `natbib` following this question here: [Beamer and Natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/beamer-and-natbib)

Consequently, the MWE looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,hideothersubsections]{beamer}

%-------style of references------
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{round,comma,aysep={,}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%-----------

%------LAYOUT--------
\usetheme{Warsaw}%vordefiniertes Layout.
\usecolortheme{wolverine}%vordefinierte Farbgebung.
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}%Schriftart.

%---------------
%Content titlepage:
\title[]{title}
\date[]{\today}
\author[]{author}
\institute{institution}
%--------------

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\begin{frame}[plain]
\hspace*{-\beamer@leftsidebar}%
\advance\textwidth by \beamer@leftsidebar\relax
\beamer@leftsidebar=\z@
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\par%
  \maketitle
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\makeatother

\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\begin{frame}
    text 1
\end{frame}

\section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame}
    text 2
\end{frame}

\section{section 3}
\subsection{subsection 3.1}
\begin{frame}
    text 3
\end{frame}


%\section[]{References}

\begin{frame}{}
\scriptsize

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{MAbib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I do not know how to implement in the MWE a source for `bibtex`. Hopefully it is working anyway.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: By default, beamer doesn't add any title for the bibliography to the sidebar. Can you please edit your question and add there a simple, complete document illustrating the problem and showing the relevant settings used and the way you build your bibliography?

Comment: Also, `Warsaw` doesn't use a sidebar by default, so please do as I suggested above and give us a MWE reproducing the problem mentioned.

Comment: In case anybody uses biber as backend, the following post (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436539/how-to-delete-the-word-references-from-the-navigation-bar-in-beamer) shows how it's done then. (Which is basicall: just use '\printbibliography[heading=none]")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Form your MWE, it is clear that you want to suppress the entry from the *navigation bar* and not from the sidebar.

Anyways, I can offer you two options:

1) To use `\appendix` just before your bibliography (the entry will still appear in the navigation bar but not in the "main" navigation bar but on a navigation of its own):

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,hideothersubsections]{beamer}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usetheme{Warsaw}%vordefiniertes Layout.
\usecolortheme{wolverine}%vordefinierte Farbgebung.
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}%Schriftart.

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@article{testa,
  author = {The A Author},
  year = {2014},
  title = {The title A},
  journal = {The journal A},
  pages = {1--5},
}
@article{testb,
  author = {The B Author},
  year = {2014},
  title = {The title B},
  journal = {The journal B},
  pages = {6--10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}

\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\begin{frame}
    text 1
\end{frame}

\section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame}
    text 2
\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}{}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

2) Redefine `\bibsection` to be, for example, `\section[]{\refname}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,hideothersubsections]{beamer}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usetheme{Warsaw}%vordefiniertes Layout.
\usecolortheme{wolverine}%vordefinierte Farbgebung.
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}%Schriftart.

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@article{testa,
  author = {The A Author},
  year = {2014},
  title = {The title A},
  journal = {The journal A},
  pages = {1--5},
}
@article{testb,
  author = {The B Author},
  year = {2014},
  title = {The title B},
  journal = {The journal B},
  pages = {6--10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand\bibsection{\section[]{\refname}}

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}

\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\begin{frame}
    text 1
\end{frame}

\section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame}
    text 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gonzalo Medina! In the end I have opted for the first solution since it seems to be a little bit easier. It works exactly the way I want it to.

Comment: The second option from GonzaloMedina did not work for me. I got and error. Instead I used `\renewcommand\bibsection{\section*{\refname}}` and it worked perfectly. Thanks to GonzaloMedina