# How to delete the word 'References' from the navigation bar in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I am currently preparing a beamer presentation and I would like to do something I haven't been able to achieve on my own. I would really like to get the word "References" out of the top navigation bar. See the screenshot below to see what I mean.

[image]

An (almost) MWE that produces the above output without warnings is the following:

```
\documentclass[beaver,8pt,compress,notheorems,xcolor={svgnames},hyperref={colorlinks,allcolors=blue}]{beamer}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[upright]{fourier} % My favourite font.
\usepackage[isbn=false,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace} % To format text line spacing.

% FONT DEFINITIONS

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}

% TO GET BULLETS ON TOP

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\normalsize}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@listii{\itemsep4pt}
\makeatletter

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-1.75ex}{}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{20.00pt}

\setbeamercolor{mini frame}{bg=blue, fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{mini frame current frame}{fg=blue}

\makeatletter
\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#2>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
    \fi%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
  \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
  \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
  \kern\beamer@tempdim
  \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
  \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
      \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
      \ifnum\c@section>#1%
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
            %\usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
%            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
          \else%
            \ifnum\c@section=#1%
              \ifnum\c@subsection>#2%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
              \else%
                \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
                  \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
                  \ifnum\c@subsectionslide<#3%
                    \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%
                  \else%
                    \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame current frame}
                    \fi 
                    \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
                  \fi%
                \else%
                  \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
                  \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%
                \fi%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%
            \fi%
          \fi%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
  }
\makeatother

% BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS

\addbibresource{Bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textsc{Introduction}}
\framesubtitle{\textsc{\normalsize{}}}

\citet{hartmascolell} is an awesome paper.

\end{frame}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\emergencystretch=1em

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textsc{References}}
\framesubtitle{\textsc{\normalsize{}}}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With the convenient .bib file named Bib.bib and stored in the same folder as the main .tex:

```
@article{hartmascolell,
author = "S. Hart and A. Mas-Colell",
title = "Bargaining and Value",
journal = "Econometrica",
volume = "64",
pages = "357--380",
year = "1996",
url = "https://doi.org/10.2307/2171787"
}
```

Then, my question is: **how can I delete the word References from the navigation bar?**

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time.

Comment: I don't see that when I compile your code. maybe a `.aux` file clean up does the trick?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I'm very sorry, I forgot to add the Bib file. My bad. I have already added the information of the Bib.bib file to the MWE of the original question. I hope this solves the issue.

Comment: You might be interested in the solution to the follwing related question: [How to hide references from navigation bar in beamer class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187877/134144)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. For some reason that I don't know, the solution suggested in that question causes an error in my MWE.

Comment: @Héctor: The second solution indeed causes an error. Using `\appendix` right before the `frame` with the references should work as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `\printbibliography` automatically creates an unnumbered section. This can be switched off `\printbibliography[heading=none]`. However then an addition miniframe would be shown in the previous section. With a little bit of hacking this can be switched off.
- instead of manually specifying the font in every frametitle, you could use `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\scshape}`

---

```
\documentclass[beaver,8pt,compress,notheorems,xcolor={svgnames},hyperref={colorlinks,allcolors=blue}]{beamer}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[upright]{fourier} % My favourite font.
\usepackage[isbn=false,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace} % To format text line spacing.

% FONT DEFINITIONS

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}

% TO GET BULLETS ON TOP

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\normalsize}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@listii{\itemsep4pt}
\makeatletter

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-1.75ex}{}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{20.00pt}

\setbeamercolor{mini frame}{bg=blue, fg=blue}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativit\"atstheorie},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\scshape}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\citet{einstein} is an awesome paper.
\end{frame}

\miniframesoff

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]