# Extract from URL field in beamer

Tags: beamer, natbib, urls

How can I extract the value of the URL field of an entry in a `.bib` file? 
I want to print it directly in the `frame` of my `beamer` document.

Additional info: (added July 20, 2014):

I can't provide the exact copy of the .tex file because it's very long now. In my preamble  I have

```
\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

and in the document I have

```
 \begin{document}
 \nobibliography{database}
 .... 

 \citet{Jilvero2012} % I want to print the URL here%

 ...
 \end{document}
```

this key is defined in my .bib file as

```
@Article{Jilvero2012,
   Title                    = {Heat requirement for regeneration of aqueous ammonia in post-combustion carbon dioxide capture },
   Author                   = {Henrik Jilvero and Fredrik Normann and Klas Andersson and Filip Johnsson},
   Journal                  = {International Journal of Greenhouse Gas Control },
   Year                     = {2012},
   Number                   = {0},
  Pages                    = {181 - 187},
   Volume                   = {11},

  Doi                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ijggc.2012.08.005},
  ISSN                     = {1750-5836},
  Keywords                 = {Chilled ammonia},
   Url                      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1750583612001909}
 }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can use the package `usebib`: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/usebib

Comment: This procedure requires me to change the format of my bib file and I have a big bib file so its not practical for me to do so. The documentation also cautions the use of usebib for large bib files. But thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you seen [`beamer` and `natbib`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1969/5764)? Can you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: Why not `biblatex`? Regarding `usebib`, if your `.bib` file uses `"` for delimiting fields, you're out of luck, because `usebib` employs TeX macros for doing its job and, since `"` is a valid character in fields, there's not much one can do about it.

Comment: Are you open to using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)?

Comment: Yes @werner. Actually I have another related question in this group.

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192248/problems-in-citing-in-beamer

Answer (score 2):

Using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), `\citeurl{<bibkey>}` will print the URL associated with the citation key `<bibkey>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Jilvero2012,
   Title                    = {Heat requirement for regeneration of aqueous ammonia in post-combustion carbon dioxide capture },
   Author                   = {Henrik Jilvero and Fredrik Normann and Klas Andersson and Filip Johnsson},
   Journal                  = {International Journal of Greenhouse Gas Control },
   Year                     = {2012},
   Number                   = {0},
  Pages                    = {181 - 187},
   Volume                   = {11},

  Doi                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ijggc.2012.08.005},
  ISSN                     = {1750-5836},
  Keywords                 = {Chilled ammonia},
   Url                      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1750583612001909}
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \cite{Jilvero2012}

  \citeurl{Jilvero2012}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can also work with BibTeX by passing the option `backend=bibtex` to `biblatex` at loading time.

Comment: Great!!! 
It's working now! I just used the backend=bibtex!
Many thanks @Werner