# Problems in citing in Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I'm trying to cite an article in a `frame` and display the URL at the same time (`Beamer`). But all I get for the citation is a print out of the key. As for the URL I can't make it work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{science.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
     In  \textcite{Jilvero2012181} found in   --i want to print the url here--%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`science.bib` is in the same folder with the main `.tex` document. The `.bib` file contains the following

```
@article{Jilvero2012181,
title = "Heat requirement for regeneration of aqueous ammonia in post-combustion       carbon dioxide capture ",
journal = "International Journal of Greenhouse Gas Control ",
volume = "11",
number = "0",
pages = "181 - 187",
year = "2012",
note = "",
issn = "1750-5836",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ijggc.2012.08.005",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1750583612001909",
author = "Henrik Jilvero and Fredrik Normann and Klas Andersson and Filip Johnsson",
keywords = "Chilled ammonia",
keywords = "Post-combustion",
keywords = "\{CO2\} capture",
keywords = "Aqueous ammonia",
keywords = "Heat requirement "
}
```

I am using TeXworks. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As an aside, I don't think that displaying the URL on the slide would be very useful - much better to put the first author, journal, volume and page (and perhaps the title). Then people can write a quick note and look it up later. You can use `\fullcite` to display this information. But of course, if you will be distributing the slides, then the URL might be useful :-)

Comment: I am poor in English langue and Istart to learn webside myself. so Ican do mistake and forgive me.

Comment: You have to run `pdflatex - biber - pdflatex [- pdflatex]`. do you do that?

Comment: @musicman I don't have this biber. I tried to install it after your comment but I always get the error

   'The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer. Try installing the program to fix this problem.'

But i have cygwin64 installed already.

Comment: maybe this related Q&A can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192410/winedit-problem-with-biblatex-cygwin1-dll