# Can I use natbib with beamer?

Tags: beamer, natbib

Can I somehow use natbib with beamer now? When I try to load the natbib package the file does not compile. There is some old evidence that there is a conflict here:  [Beamer and Natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/beamer-and-natbib/1970#1970). But maybe this is now rectified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic `natbib` use does work with `beamer`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Herrmann1999,
  Title                    = {Ruthenium carbene complexes with imidazolin-2-ylidene ligands allow the formation of tetrasubstituted cycloalkenes by RCM},
  Author                   = {Ackermann, Lutz and Fürstner, Alois and Weskamp, Thomas and Kohl, Florian J. and Herrmann, Wolfgang A.},
  Journal                  = {Tetrahedron Lett.},
  Year                     = {1999},
  Number                   = {26},
  Pages                    = {4787-4790},
  Volume                   = {40},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 Hello world~\cite{Herrmann1999}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that as Till says in the manual, references (certainly those in a 'bibliography' at the end) work poorly in a presentation. As such, functionality in this area is somewhat limited.

Comment: @JosephWrightIt seems to me that the inputenc package here makes input sensitive in particular ways. What do I need to be aware of?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal I've only used `'inputenc` as my demo bibliography entry has a non-ASCII char in it. Nowadays, most people save their input as UTF-8, which for most European languages will work with pdfTeX with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.