# How to cite a reference on Beamer as (author, year)

Tags: beamer, citing

How can I change the citation style to "( author , year )" on beamer? The code is for "author year"

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ppgeq.bib}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{\secname}{\subsecname}
\cite{Wang2005}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Can I use natbib with beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258419/can-i-use-natbib-with-beamer) (answer: yes, at least for the test case provided)

Comment: Now that I look more closely, you're not really using natbib, you're using biblatex with a similar style. There are [several references to people using biblatex and beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex+beamer), so certainly it should work in general. Have you used biblatex with other documents before? Have you used this .bib file in those documents? Does it work if you remove either or both of the options in your `\usepackage` line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend using `biber` (the default) instead of `bibtex` as the back end for using `biblatex`.  With the standard author-year style, there are two main citation commands:

- `\textcite{}` produces Author yyyy
- `\parencite{}` produces (Author yyyy)

To get the comma between the name and the year, you need:

- `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}`

So here's a complete example of what you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}
\end{filecontents}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame title}
\begin{itemize}
\item Langue et parole \parencite{Saussure1995}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For printing the bibliography, you should typically use `[allowframebreaks]` on the frame that contains the `\printbibliography` command.

[image: output of slide]

Comment: As I asked for a authoryear comma separated style, just add "\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}" after "\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}" and it will totally answer my question.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that. Just added it now.

Comment: I just found this answer. When I compile your example with `pdflatex` and `bibtex` and add a cite slide containing `\printbibliography` that slide simply remains empty in the final PDF.

Comment: @Peter You need to use with `biber` rather than `bibtex` to process the bibliography.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, biber was initially producing an error so I assumed I had to use bibtex, but I tried this again and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I think this can solve the problem. Just add the `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` before the `\bibliography{}`. I used it on beamer and works fine.

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Referências}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{bibliografia.bib}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: `\bibliographystyle` is used by natbib, not biblatex. The original question is using biblatex (which may be used because they want the references printed on the same slide, not in a bibliography at the end). Without including a preamble that imports compatible packages, this answer does not work. So in context, it is wrong, even though it would be good in a different context.