# Biblatex in beamer not adding extradate letter

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, apa-style

I am using biblatex in beamer to manage both my bibliography and my in-text citations after having read the following post: [How to cite a reference on Beamer as (author, year)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315627/how-to-cite-a-reference-on-beamer-as-author-year).

However, I am left with one problem I am not able to solve:

1. I have two identical author-year documents, and biblatex is not inserting an extra letter after the year to differentiate the two (both in the in-text citation and in the bibliography):
   [image]

What I would like to have is:

- (BCBS, 2013a)
- (BCBS, 2013b, 2014)

The same in the bibliography.

Here is the code of the text file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[bibstyle=apa, citestyle = apa, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography/Library_New}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} 
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\tiny} 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\newenvironment{trienv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]}}{}
\newenvironment{squareenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]}}{}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{rotating} 

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Citations}
In text: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item \parencite{BCBS_RCAP2013_RWA}
    \item \parencite{BCBSNewMotto2013,BCBSNewMotto2014}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography[sorting=nty]   
    
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

and the code of the bib file:

```
@techreport{BCBSNewMotto2013,
author = {{BCBS}},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
institution = {Bank for International Settlements},
isbn = {9291319406},
number = {October},
pages = {1--23},
title = {{Discussion paper - The regulatory framework: balancing risk sensitivity, simplicity and comparability}},
url = {https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs258.htm},
year = {2013}
}

@techreport{BCBS_RCAP2013_RWA,
author = {BCBS},
institution = {Bank for International Settlements},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
abstract = {This document is called BCBS 256. This is where it all started (Basel IV). This document outlines for the first time "formally" the huge variability registered within the RWA computations across banks.},
isbn = {929131966X},
keywords = {BCBS},
number = {October},
pages = {57},
title = {{Regulatory Consistency Assessment Programme (RCAP) – Analysis of risk-weighted assets for credit risk in the banking book}},
year = {2013}
}

@techreport{BCBSNewMotto2014,
abstract = {This document is called BCBS 306. This document introduces for the first time the motto: greater simplicity, comparability and risk sensitivity of the risk-weighted assets computations.},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
author = {{BCBS}},
isbn = {9789291973804},
keywords = {BCBS},
number = {December 2014},
pages = {12},
institution = {{Bank for International Settlements}},
title = {{Consultative document - Capital floors: the design of a framework based on standardised approaches}},
year = {2014}
}
```

Any idea why this could be, and how I might solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The style you use can't be used with the `bibtex` backend, it requires biber

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you only show two bib entries in your question with different years. Where should the extrayear marker come into play?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you don't need to load all the `ams*` packages, beamer already loads them for you. Same for graphics and hyperref. Don't load `enumerate` with beamer, you will undo much of beamer's special adjustments to itemize/enumerate environments. If your latex distribution is up to date you don't need to load the inputenc package, `utf8` is now the default. In `\addbibressource` the file name is missing the `.bib` suffix. Better not mess with link colours in beamer, this will undo the careful adjustments of the colour themes.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to add the "BCBS_RCAP2013_RWA"  document in the bib file. Sorry, but I had to extract an example from a much larger presentation. Here it is modified in the bib file.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If I switch to biber, your code works fine  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQTRG.png

Comment: By switching to biber you mean changing only: \usepackage[bibstyle=apa, citestyle = apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}. Because if I do that, all the rest being equal, then I have the keywords being printed and the bibliography disappears... I am using Overleaf, thanks a lot !

Comment: You might have to compile from scratch, e.g. deleting all the auxiliary files

Comment: Could you explain me what do you mean by compile from scratch ? Thanks :)

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303806/how-to-erase-lof-file-and-other-auxiliary-files-in-overleaf

Comment: I have done all the modifications you suggested, and Recompiled from scratch, following: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache. Unfortunately, it doesn't work...

Comment: Seems to work fine on overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/vwqdkjsnpzsk

Comment: Thank you very much for you file example @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ! Strangely, it works only if I create a new bib file, a shorter one compared to my full bibliography file, only containing the documents I need to cite in the slides document... Is this a common problem of biber ? It cannot handle large bib files ? (my bib file works fine in the article class document)

Comment: Usually the size does not matter, but there might be some error in you bib file which prevents biber from creating the bibliography.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking... However, I am not able to find them manually, as no error is indicated, and no error appears in my article document class... Strange... Nonetheless, again a big thank you for your help! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: If you make a copy, cite only one entry while removing half of the entries you should be able to narrow down in which half the error is. Repeat as many times as needed to locate it.

Comment: Biber errors are noted in the `.blg` file. You can download the `.blg` file as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 for the `.bbl` file. The `.blg` file is a simple text file that can be opened with any text editor (Windows might classify it as a "performance monitor file", but it is just a text file). That file should contain information about errors that Biber encounters.