# Beamer-compatible bibliography style with URL or DOI and numbered referencing

Tags: bibliographies, ieee-style

## I am looking for a bibliography style which:

- orders items as they are cited (“unsorted”)
- prints bracketed numbers for the reference
- is compatible with the `beamer` class
- prints either the DOI or the URL (both are also ok if just one isn't possible).

Basically:

[image]

## I have tried:

#### `unsrt`

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

which is nice but does not include DOI/URL:

[image]

#### `natbib` with `unsrtnat`

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\setcitestyle{square,numbers}
```

which gives me all I want (well, it gives me both URL and DOI, but that's okish), however completely breaks (formatting-wise) in beamer:

[image]

#### `IEEEtran`

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

which actually gives me all I want, but somewhat breaks formatting-wise in beamer:

[image]

#### adding various commands (e.g. `\newcommand*{\howpublished}[1]{\doi}`) while using the `unsrt` class

which did nothing.

Comment: It's a bit mysterious as to why or how the `unsrtnat` and `IIIEtran` bibliography style would "break formatting-wise" in a `beamer` document. Please tell us more about how you create citation call-outs and the bibliography. Please also clarify what "breaks formatting-wise" means for you.

Comment: `beamer` and `natbib` don't quite work together, which means that loading `natbib` undoes many of the modifications `beamer` applies to the bibliography (the colour, the icons, ...). See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1969/35864.

Comment: @Mico please have a look at the edit, does this help you help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

package `biblatex` with options `sorting=none,style=numeric,doi=true` should work.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the biblatex package? It's not included in the standard TeXlive distribution, and it intoduces a number of other formatting errors, much like natbib does: https://chymera.eu/ppb/9da996.png